# Problem with LED driver - LEDs do not switch on when button is pressed

Tags: led, digital-logic

The below circuit is not working how I'd expect it to.

[image: schematic]

The circuit has two parts, the top half is a battery charger that takes in 5V and charges a battery. The bottom half is an LED driver, that should turn LEDs1-4 on or off when SW1 is pressed.

The charging circuit is working, I can see that the charge LED (connected to U1 CHRG) lights up, and the voltage across the battery is 4V, but when I press SW1 I do not see LED1-4 come on, so there's something wrong in that half of the circuit.

Datasheets:
[74LVC1G74 D-type flip-flop](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/74LVC1G74.pdf)
[LP5522 LED driver](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lp5522.pdf)

Comment: Is the problem with the expected On/Off switching?  Or is it that the LEDs do not light up equally?  It also seems that the LP5522 has a maximum output of slightly over 20 mA.

Comment: The problem is that the LED's do not switch on. I can see the charging circuit just not the LEDs turn on.

Comment: Here's an issue with the question: Conflicting information. Your Q: *So the charging circuit dosen't work* then your comment: *I can see the charging circuit just not the LEDs turn on* Another thing is that this is "your" design, it would be nice if you included what steps you have made in order to troubleshoot the issue(s).

Comment: Please probe all relevant nodes and report back.

Comment: Ok just to clarify. The charging circuit works. I have 4 V across the batt terminals. However when SW1  is pressed the LEDs do not turn on. I hope this clarifies.

Comment: Previously it was _"charging circuit dosen't work"_, now it's _"The charging circuit works"_. Which is it? Don't sprinkle vital information in comments. Edit the original question to include all the relevant information. Name nodes in your schematic and refer to them for all your measurements.

Comment: Are you getting the expected signal switching on the CTRL pin?  As in my comment, the LED output is limited to about 20 mA. Have you tried using a single LED rather than four? Also, an Riset value of 24 K is recommended to reach this maximum current. The Iset pin can also be connected to VDD for a 5 mA output.

Comment: ( More clarification from the OP and answers to earlier requests in comments would still help. However, after the question's recent edit which collected information that had been put into comments, I see that an answer is possible so I'll reopen it. )

Comment: I’m not getting any change of state at pin 5 on U3. I will try and install just one LED tonight and give the feedback. Thanks

Comment: Have you checked that the LEDs still work, independently of that circuit?

Comment: The LEDs have been on another circuit that does work. I’m getting no Voltage at the LED terminals

Answer (score 1):

If you expect the 7474 to act as a divide-by-two you need to pull the *set* and *reset* pins **high**, not low. You should refer to the truth table in the data sheet.

You have other issues:

1. The simple switch to toggle the flip-flop needs to be debounced. Mechanical switches can switch many times for each actuation due to contact bounce and dirt on the contacts.
2. It is better to put LEDs in series. You may get current hogging with paralleled LEDs. With paralleled LEDs, since your compliance voltage is fairly low, perhaps placing a small valued resistor (perhaps 20 ohms) in series with each LED may help with current sharing.
3. When you power up the circuit, the initial flip-flop state will be unknown with both the set and reset pins pulled high. This means the LED could be on or off when power is applied to the circuit. You may want to try something as simple as a R-C circuit (R pulling the pin high, C from pin to ground) tied to either the set or reset pins as a power-up-reset circuit.

Comment: 1. Should I move the switch the other side of R7?

Comment: 2. I will try using just one LED tonight. I’ll also try using another resistor in series. Thanks

Comment: @Handsome Google "mechanical switch debouncing" if you're not familiar with it, swapping the switch and resistor won't help. If you can probe the output of U5, you will see it toggle rapidly if you're having bouncing issues. Using just one LED is a good idea for now while you debug the circuit, set the POT halfway as well to be sure the resistance is in the right reigion.

Answer (score 0):

The maximum recommended *total* output current is 20 mA.  Per the datasheet, the minimum current setting resistor value is 24K.  The driver might be shutting down due to overtemperature caused by overloading its output stage.  I did not see any mention of overcurrent protection in the datasheet, but that also might be going on.

Separate from that, there is no switch debouncing on the flipflop input.  This could be causing multiple, rapid edges into the LED driver.  The driver can be programmed with multiple edges on its control input.  It might be acting on switch bounces as programming commands.

Comment: Hi al,l I did not get time last night to check out the suggestions to be made. Hopefully tonight.